# DB2 V9.7 upgrade failure

Tags: db2

I'm upgrading a V9.1 to a v9.7

The scripts for compatibility checks pass but

> /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/instance/db2iupgrade
>   -d -u db2fenc1 db2inst1

fails with the following error message:

```
db2: symbol lookup error: db2: undefined symbol: sqltGetCompTraceFlag
Update DBM cfg SYSADM_GROUP errcode = 127
DBI1281E  The database manager configuration file could not be
      initialized.
...
```

According to the script log it chokes on get_db2dir_ver() from db2iutil. If I run the command manually as:

> /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2fupdt -f
>   /home/db2inst1/sqllib/ctrl/.instuse -p
>   DB2DIR

I get:

> ```
> /opt/ibm/db2/V9.1
> ```

I have lost hope...

Comment: Might help if you also tell us what OS.

Comment: 5 seconds of Google also suggests that you should run this and see if there's any hints in there : db2grep -dump

Comment: RedHat Linux 5.5 and there's no db2grep on the fs

Comment: Aha - typo on someone's part. db2greg -dump works on my AIX systems.

Comment: Have you had a chance to run db2greg -dump? What were the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poring over the setup one more time, it was discovered that the 9.1 instance paths were hardcoded in the machine-wide /etc/profile.

It's a big RTFM and I'd like to beat myself for this: I did look into the file but didn't actually page down to check all of it... and the export was at the end.